# Removing shadow from button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, shadow

I've created style for button in my WPF app:

```
<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border
                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then I'm putting this style to Button control:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Press"/>
```

When I'm running my app, I see grey shadow under and right of the button. Futhermore when I look in Visual Studio view I don't see shadow. How can I delete this effect? Anyone an idea or an completly other approach?

Comment: I just pasted your example into an empty WPF project, and I don't see any gray shadow. Just a button that turns red when you hover over it. Maybe you have some other styles that are unintentionally being applied to the button?

Comment: You can't have a shadow on a control in WPF unless you explicitly set the `Effect` property... you don't have this in this code example. Perhaps if you search your code for `Effect`, you'll find where you added it?

Comment: No I haven't any other styles and any Effects. This effect you can see, when you run application. Please compare the edges of the button, after running application. As you can see one of them have little shadow. I've pasted this code in blank project and I have still problem. @Sheridan I'm running app in Windows 8.1.

Comment: As @GrantWinney told you, your problem shadow is *not* part of your example code. I can confirm this and on Windows 8.1 as well. Until you provide some code that actually demonstrates your problem, I have voted to close this question as there is nothing that we can do to help at this stage. I will of course be happy to remove my close vote if and when you edit your question with a working code example.

Comment: Are you sure it's a shadow and not just a blurred edge?  WPF layout is based on device-independent pixels, so it's possible for an element's edge to reside between two device pixels, in which case it may appear blurred.  Can you post a screenshot to show us how it looks?

Comment: MikeStrobel you're right. I have tried run my app from another computer and I don't see blurred edges. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch @MikeStrobel. Can you post your comment as an answer so that this question can be marked as answered please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure what you're seeing is actually a shadow?  It could simply be a blurred edge.  WPF's layout system is based on device-independent pixels, so it's possible for an element's edge to reside between two device pixels, in which case it may appear blurred.

You can force device-pixel snapping by setting `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on a parent element in WPF 4.0 and later; in earlier versions, you can try `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`.